# Differentiation with respect to time

Tags: derivatives

I have a simple question: If
$$\mu_t=\frac{1}{H_t}$$
then when I differentiate with respect to time, does it hold

$$\dot{\mu}_t=\frac{1}{\dot{H}_t}$$

Comment: No, it will be $\dot{\mu_t} = -H_t^{-2}\dot{H_t}$. Notice the derivative is on the numerator not the denominator. It is through the chain rule.

Comment: To see that your formula is wrong, try an example...like $\mu_t=t$.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: See [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Composite_Function) if the chain rule's unfamiliar.

Comment: @J.G. I am familiar but I wasn't sure for time-dependent variables.

Comment: @Mr.M It doesn't matter what kind of variable it is. Maths doesn't "know" whether the $x$ in $dy/dx=(dy/du)(du/dx)$ is a position or time, so it might as well be called $t$..